# Can OpenSSH options (e.g. IdentityFile) be passed in an ssh:// URL?

Tags: linux, ssh

If I open an ssh:// URL on my Mac, most popular handler applications (e.g. Apple Terminal, iTerm) know how to construct an `ssh` command using the standard parts of the URL as arguments (username, host, port).

But can the extended range of OpenSSH-style options (e.g. IdentityFile, LogLevel) be passed in a ssh:// URL to these apps?

**Or**, if this is not permitted by design, why not? (Please link to some official docs if possible in your answer.)

### Some experiments

I have tried opening the following from my browser, with Apple Terminal as the handler, without initial success:

- ssh://(me)@localhost:22/?IdentityFile=/Users/(me)/.ssh/id_rsa
- ssh://(me)@localhost:22/?identity_file=/Users/(me)/.ssh/id_rsa
- ssh://(me)@localhost:22/?i=/Users/(me)/.ssh/id_rsa

Where (me) is replaced by your username

Comment: That seems like a terrible idea.  Someone would click on an ssh url with `ForwardX11Trusted=yes` and give up control of their local system.  Or something with a `RemoteForward` setting. Yuck.

Comment: @larsks - agree on the security implications, it's probably a bad idea. My question is on whether it's possible at all. This doesn't make it a bad question per se. This would be one explanation for why it didn't work when I tried it in Apple Terminal, but a more conclusive answer sourced e.g. from some official docs would be nice.